# microservice shared domain layer

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, soa, solid-principles

I have a doubt about Microservices Architecture. We are developing an ERP and there're several microservices such as Human Resources, Identity, Orders and so on.

We've implemented a shared domain layer for entities that are common for all those layers, including abstractions ( interfaces ) of Company, Location and some value objects.

My question is: What's the boundary of shared items for microservices and how bad is that?

In that case, Those shared entities would be the same for each microservice, so that help us to write less code BUT at the same time creates a small level of coupling.

Comment: How would you share crosscutting items such as authentication for instance? I have 10+ microservices that share a JWT between all of them in order to use a single authentication. Should I pack those items into a Nuget Package? What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually microservice architectures adopt a "share nothing" concept, which mean your code bases should be ideally separate. Yes, that will mean you will write more code but will keep your microservices more manageable, uncoupled and probably lighter.

Also, regarding the DDD-part do the question, you should really strive to keep well defined boundaries within your application, which means you shouldn't be scared to have "redundant" entities in different bounded contexts because the same concept usually mean different things to different domain areas of your application.

Keeping onto the "ERP" theme, you'd expect the "Order Placing" context of your application to have quite a different view on the "Product" entity than that of the "Tax" context. Keeping those in distinct contexts in different code bases will allow you to model smaller aggregates with a higher level of cohesion that will be way less coupled to the other constructs of your model thus, making evolve your microservices way easier.

Comment: I see. So you're basically saying that under no circumstance there's a core domain in this case nor shared domains nor crosscutting between the microservices. That'd violate the microservices concept.

Comment: The microservices concept, yeah. But please keep in mind none of these rules are set in stone. Sometimes DDD practitioners do reuse code (such as in the Shared Kernel patterns between boundaries) so, in order to achieve your goals, you'll probably have to find some middle ground and compromise.

My point was only pointing out the "normal" principles are applied to keep higher cohesion, lower coupling and better evolutionary capabilities in your code base and I stand by that. But defining architectures is all about compromising where you can, and protecting the characteristics you must keep.

Comment: How would you share crosscutting items such as authentication for instance? I have 10+ microservices that share a JWT between all of them in order to use a single authentication. Should I pack those items into a Nuget Package? What would be the best approach?

Comment: I don't actually consider that "cross-cutting". It's more like a shared library that every one of your 10+ microservices will use. Since you're using JWT, you're probably better embedding the token inside the header of every request, and in the earliest stages of your pipeline attach the library which will decode/validate it and either abort the request or let it continue. That way, your services aren't actually sharing anything, they're all just using a jwt validation library (the same way multiple microservices of yours might use the same ORM).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: What's the boundary of shared items for microservices and how bad is that?

Up until a few years ago it was complicated to get the boundaries a microservice defined because there was simply no agreement on how to archieve that, but Evans sorted that out a few years ago:

[GOTO 2015 • DDD & Microservices: At Last, Some Boundaries! • Eric Evans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPvef9R3k-M)

Microservices also follow the four tenants of SOA and the same 9 fallacies of distributed system are to take in consideration nevertheless their business scopes are different. Bear in mind that a microservice architecture should follow a Shared-nothing sort of architecture, so services don't really share entities, what they do is subscribe to messages, typically in a bus, and store local copies of the pieces of data they are interested in. This obviously introduce another concept called eventual consistency and depending on your business requirements,that might or might not if in your overall design.